# Calculate Lq and Ld of a motor with HFI

Tags: motor, inductor

I have seen several papers, where Lq and Ld are calculated by injecting a rotating voltage vector
for Vd or Vq at a fixed frequency. I already made an implementation on a controller and it seems to work somehow, but not with high accuracy and repeatability.

So, I might have a problem somewhere in my understanding/implementation.

The calculation for Lq should go like this:

$$\frac{V_d(\omega)}{I_d(\omega)} = R + j\omega L_d $$
$$ Im[\frac{V_d(\omega)}{I_d(\omega)} ] = \omega L_d$$

Further at a fixed frequency :

$$V_d(\omega_0) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_n^N{v_d(nT_s) e^{-j\omega_0 n T_s}} = a_{1,v_d} - j b_{1,vd}$$

So the coefficients a1 and b1 can be calculated:

$$a_{1,v_d} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_n^N{v_d(nT_s) cos({\omega_0 n T_s})}$$
$$b_{1,v_d} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_n^N{v_d(nT_s) sin({\omega_0 n T_s})}$$

The same goes for Id

Then finally:

$$L_d = \frac{1}{\omega_0} \frac {a_{1,v_d} * b_{1,i_d} - a_{1,i_d} * b_{1,v_d}}{a_{1,i_d}^2 + b_{1,i_d}^2}$$

The theory should work, if the signals are good enough and there might be my problem.
What I do now is applying the Vd vector and rotating the electrical angle with 500Hz. The sampling time is 5kHz, so there are 10 datapoints for one period. I measure in total 5000 datapoints and average the coefficients a1 and b1 from above, still I got in every iteration a deviation up to 200% and especially the calcualted value is strongly from the applied Vd value dependents and the calculated Ld goes up with a higher applied rotating Vd vector.

For the calucaltions, I directly use
$$Vd = A * sin(2\pi\omega_0 T_s)$$

And the current I measure directly over the current shunt sensors. So, might I use a band pass filter? Is the applied method a valid one for calcualting Ld and Lq? Are there more easy methods to do so?

Here is also a plot from 200 samples:
[image]

Edit: I wrote a pyhton script, and there I can reproduce the problem pretty good, when I add some noise on the Amplitude of Id (around 33%). There must be another problem with my implementation:

[image]

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

Vd = []
Id = []
t = []
omega_0 = 500
omega_s = 5000
Vd_amp = 800
Id_amp = 150
Pi = 3.141592

a1_vd = 0;
a1_id = 0;
b1_vd = 0;
b1_id = 0;

iter = 0
max_iter = 5000

ran_interval_amp = 50;
ran_interval_phase = 0;

tt = 0;

Ld = []

def ind_cal():
    global Vd, Id, t, tt, iter, a1_vd, b1_vd, a1_id, b1_id, omega_0, omega_s, Vd_amp, Id_amp, Pi, ran_interval_amp, ran_interval_phase, Ld;
    Vd = []
    Id = []
    t = []
    tt =0
    iter = 0;

    while iter < max_iter:
        Vd.append(Vd_amp*math.sin(2*Pi*iter*omega_0/omega_s));
        Id.append(Id_amp * math.cos(2*Pi*iter*omega_0/omega_s*(1 + random.uniform(-ran_interval_phase,ran_interval_phase))) + random.uniform(-ran_interval_amp,ran_interval_amp));
        t.append(tt);

        tt = tt + 1/omega_s;
        iter = iter + 1;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while i < max_iter / omega_s/omega_0:
        j = 0;
        while j < omega_s/omega_0:
            angle = 2*Pi*j*omega_0/omega_s;
            a1_vd = a1_vd + Vd[int(j + i * omega_s / omega_0)] * math.cos(angle);
            b1_vd = a1_vd + Vd[int(j + i * omega_s / omega_0)] * math.sin(angle);
            a1_id = a1_vd + Id[int(j + i * omega_s / omega_0)] * math.cos(angle);
            b1_id = a1_vd + Id[int(j + i * omega_s / omega_0)] * math.sin(angle);

            j = j + 1;
        i = i + 1;

    a1_vd = a1_vd / max_iter;
    b1_vd = b1_vd / max_iter;
    a1_id = a1_id / max_iter;
    b1_id = b1_id / max_iter;

    LLd = (a1_vd * b1_id - a1_id * b1_vd) / (2*Pi*omega_0 * (a1_id*a1_id + b1_id * b1_id));
    if(LLd < 0):
        LLd = LLd * -1;
    Ld.append(LLd);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1,10):
        ind_cal();
    print(Ld)

    plt.plot(Ld)
    plt.ylabel('Ld')
    plt.show()
```